# Why is my chrome failing to download some files?

Tags: google-chrome, download

Often my Chrome fails to download a file (`Failed - Network error`). When i try to download it with Opera or Firefox it downloads without a problem. If i try multiple times with chrome it keeps failing. What is causing this behavior? Could it be spyware, compatibility bugs am i one of the few or does this happen to most?

It feels like this happens more often when I try to download from busy file hosting sites but I did not put sufficient research in this to say for sure. I love chrome but this has been a common problem for maybe over a year now and no updates fixed it.

Comment: What file types fail to download? Perhaps restricted download of some file types, e.g. executables...

Comment: Have to check on that but would it not specify that instead of "network error"?

Comment: im having the same problem, i have tried many different options and nothing seems to work so i am going to Firefox for the files that wont download until someone has a solution or chrome fixes it because it IS very enoying and it is slowing everything down. For me its not every download its seem like anything thats over a 5mb is getting this error.

Comment: It's 2021 now and I'm still having this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check for malware
2. Make sure Google Chrome is allowed in your antivirus and firewall settings
3. Adjust your proxy settings
4. Clear your cookies:

   a. Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.

   b. Select Settings.

   c. Click Show advanced settings.

   d. In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings .

   e. In the "Cookies" section, click the All cookies and site data.

   f. Click Remove all.

   g. Click X to close the dialog.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably that Chrome seems to struggle with large file downloads, at least in the case of using ajax to grab the data and then creating the file in the client.

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374157/angular-save-file-as-csv-result-in-failed-network-error-only-on-chrome

Answer (score 3):

Click the **print button** > a menu will pop up. Select **Save** > **Save Document**.

Comment: I appriciate the help but my question has nothing to do with printing. I have asked this in relation to downloading a regular file.

Comment: @Madmenyo  natalieb's response is a workaround. It works. It lets you download a file that Chrome is otherwise failing to let you download.

Answer (score 1):

I determined the cause of this issue in my case.  I was using a web page with an export to Excel button but it was actually saving a HTML file with an XLS suffix so that Excel would be used to open the HTML.  This works as intended - Excel converted the HTML table to a spreadsheet but I am thinking Chrome thinks something shady is going on because the file content is not really what the file suffix suggests.  The other browsers must not check for that.

Comment: Similar issue downloading a loan statement from Chase. Chrome can display the PDF but the download link in the Chrome PDF viewer gives a network error. Right-click and you get the HTML file only. In Firefox, a left-click downloads the PDF.

Answer (score -1):

when failed- network error appears I click the customize and control goggle chrome icon click downloads click resume works for me

Comment: I can’t quite make out what you’re saying.  Perhaps adding punctuation (and checking spelling) would help. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: resume is disbled in this case